# PasswordResetConfirmView's PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT Message if expired

Tags: django

Good day SO.

How to add message if PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT is expired? I am using the django.contrib.auth PasswordResetView to get url link with token for Password Reset. Based on [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout-days), I can add PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT like this:

```
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 10
```

10 seconds just to test.

After 10 seconds pass, I tried to to refresh the page and user can still use the URL to access the `PasswordResetConfirmView` but can no longer change the password. Even using mismatched password, no response. How should I proceed with this?

For reference, this is my URL:

```
path('reset_password/', views.MyPasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name="../templates/logauth/reset_password.html",
    subject_template_name='../templates/logauth/password_reset_subject.txt',
    email_template_name='../templates/logauth/password_reset_email.html',
    html_email_template_name='../templates/logauth/password_reset_email.html',
    from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,), 
    name="reset_password"),
path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="../templates/logauth/reset_password_sent.html"), name="password_reset_done"),
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="../templates/logauth/reset_password_2.html"), name="password_reset_confirm"),
path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="../templates/logauth/reset_password_complete.html"), name="password_reset_complete"),
```

Form to alter my PasswordResetView:

```
class MyPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    field_order = ['username', 'email']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'user-input-form'}
```

View:

```
class MyPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    form_class = MyPasswordResetForm

    def form_valid(self, form):

        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email', '').lower()
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(username=username, email=email)
        except(get_user_model().DoesNotExist):
            user = None
        if user is None:
            return redirect('password_reset_done')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django provides in `PasswordResetConfirmView` class, a template context: `validlink` --> It is a **Boolean**, which returns **True** if the link (combination of *uidb64* and *token*) is valid or unused yet.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView

You can use this to do the logic inside the `password_reset_confirm.html` template like this:

```
{% if validlink %}

 <div class="content-section">
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Change Password</legend>
      {{ form }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Change password</button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>

{% else %}

 <div class="alert alert-info mt-2">
   The link you follewd has expired! To login or reset password again click 
   <a href="{% url 'login' %}">here</a>
 </div>

{% endif %}
```